# config CORS in Gorilla Mux: 403 error on POST request

Tags: reactjs, post, go, http-post, gorilla

I have an API, currently am trying to consume one of its endpoints. The endpoint is for POST requests, the endpoint is working as expected. The API is running in the cloud, I tested it with `curl` and it was perfect, then from my react app I was trying to consume it but I get `403 status code`.

Watching in the console of the browser I see that I get that error on a OPTIONS request, and the POST never get done. Here is a screenshot of the result displayed in the console:

[image]

Then, I made a simple HTML file with a form, there I placed the required inputs, and the action pointing to this endpoint and it worked pretty well. Then, I don't know where would be the error? I have enabled CORS in the API

In the API I am using Gorilla/mux and I have something like this:

```
// Set up a router and some routes
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/", handleHome)
    //some other routes

    headersOk := handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"*"})
    originsOk := handlers.AllowedOrigins([]string{"*"})
    methodsOk := handlers.AllowedMethods([]string{"GET", "HEAD", "POST", "PUT", "OPTIONS"})

    // Start http server
    port := fmt.Sprintf(":%d", SomePort)
    http.ListenAndServe(port, handlers.CORS(originsOk, headersOk, methodsOk)(r))
```

Using:

```
"github.com/gorilla/mux"
"github.com/gorilla/handlers"
```

The message that I am getting in the browser is (in Spanish):

> Solicitud desde otro origen bloqueada: la política de mismo origen
>   impide leer el recurso remoto en https://miURL (razón: falta la
>   cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin').

In English: basically the server is rejecting the request because the CORS header is not present.

So, what have I done wrong in my router configuration?

Comment: This has nothing to do with reactjs but ajax and your api in general. What request headers are you sending? If you send any headers other than those listed in https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-request-header is causing it to prefligh the request and your api is sending 403 on the OPTIONS request. Check your API.

Comment: @cowbert correct! that are the only headers that are being sent

Comment: As noted in comments at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45967591/config-cors-in-gorilla-mux it seems your request is adding an "`osn`" request header—along with adding an Access-Control-Allow-Origin that it definitely has no need to be adding—& that’s what’s triggering the browser to do the preflight OPTIONS. And as also mentioned in the comments in that other question, the problem’s that your server’s responding with a 403 for OPTIONS request to whatever URL you’re sending the request to. So you need to configure the backend to not require authentication for OPTIONS request to that route

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With [rs/cors](https://github.com/rs/cors) you should solve CORS issues pretty easily.

On your **server.go**

```
package main

import (
    . . .       
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/rs/cors"
    "../myhandler"
)

func main() {

fmt.Println("Settin up server, enabling CORS . . .")

  c := cors.New(cors.Options{
      AllowedOrigins: []string{"*"}, // All origins
      AllowedMethods: []string{"GET"}, // Allowing only get, just an example
  })

  router := mux.NewRouter()
  // Example handler
  router.HandleFunc("/test", myhandler.TestHandler())
  http.Handle("/", router)

  // Bind to port 8000 and pass our router in and pass the cors Handler
  log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000"), c.Handler(router)))

  fmt.Println("Server is ready and is listening at port :8000 . . .")

}
```

And on your **testhandler.go**, let's suppose you want to accept `Content-Type: application/json`

```
. . .

func TestHandler func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    return
}
```