# config CORS in Gorilla Mux

Tags: go, cors, gorilla

I am working in a golang project, using gorilla/mux as the router, and now I have problems related with CORS: I cannot make a `POST` request using ajax in another application.

My current configuration for the router is as follows:

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/", handleHome)
    //Other routes

    headersOk := handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"*"})
    originsOk := handlers.AllowedOrigins([]string{"*"})
    methodsOk := handlers.AllowedMethods([]string{"GET", "HEAD", "POST", "PUT", "OPTIONS"})

    // Start http server
    port := fmt.Sprintf(":%d", some_Port)
    http.ListenAndServe(port, handlers.CORS(originsOk, headersOk, methodsOk)(r))
```

I am using:

```
"github.com/gorilla/mux"
"github.com/gorilla/handlers"
```

The message that I am getting in the browser is (in Spanish):

> Solicitud desde otro origen bloqueada: la política de mismo origen
>   impide leer el recurso remoto en https://miURL (razón: falta la
>   cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin').

In English: basically the server is rejecting the request because the CORS header is not present.

So, what have I done wrong in my router configuration?

**EDIT:**

[image: The request sent]

Comment: Can you show the headers on a response as seen in the chrome console?

Comment: @captncraig surely! I just add it at the end of the post

Comment: Looks like you are serving via caddy as well? Caddy has it's own cors plugin if thats easier, but I think your issue is the caddy proxy not allowing the headers through.

Comment: @captncraig yes, I am using Caddy. But, in that server I have others API's and they are working great. Should be an specific configuration for the site?

Comment: I believe caddy limits which headers are passed between the client and the backend. See [the proxy docs](https://caddyserver.com/docs/proxy).

Comment: Looking at the source, I am not sure if it does or does not allow the cors headers through. Can you access the app directly, without caddy, and see if it works?

Comment: @captncraig ok, let me check if accessing directly it works

Comment: @captncraig no, nothing. Worst becase not even one header is sent

Comment: The image shows you’re getting a 403 Forbidden for the CORS preflight OPTIONS request the browser’s sending. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests. That indicates the server’s requiring authentication for OPTIONS requests. It shouldn’t be. As long as the server is requiring authentication for OPTIONS requests, cross-origin requests you try to make from frontend code aren’t going be able to work. The server’s expecting an Authorization header in every request? If so, the browser doesn’t send the Authorization in the preflight OPTIONS.

Comment: I think the only reason you’re seeing that error message about the missing Access-Control-Allow-Origin is that the server only sends that header in success responses, but doesn’t send it in error responses such as the 403 response you’re getting to the OPTIONS request. But if you fix the server so that it’s sending a 200 OK or 204 for responses to OPTIONS requests, then I think you’ll get the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in that response as expected.

Comment: It would help if you use https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45967591/edit to edit/update your question to add the frontend code you’re using to make the request. Because there’s at least one problem with your request code: That code seems to be adding the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to the request. But that header is strictly a *response* header for servers to send. Adding it to requests will just break things. For one thing, adding that will trigger a CORS preflight.

Comment: Your request code also seems to be adding an "`osn`" header. So even when you remove the Access-Control-Allow-Origin from the request, that `osn` header will also still trigger a preflight OPTIONS request. So if you want to prevent the browser from doing that preflight OPTIONS, you could do that by not adding the `osn` header from the request (along with not adding the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to the request).

Comment: @sideshowbarker correct, I have that header but I need it in the backend. I don't post the code of the front because I have a generic class to dispatch all the requests and it's little difficult to post all that code here. However, i can say that it works to make POST request to others API's that are hosted in the same server because I already checked it.

Comment: I had a similar issue. I solved using [rs/cors](https://github.com/rs/cors). I made an easy configuration following the code on the Parameters tab.

Comment: @AndreaM16 totally correct! I made it and it worked